# Error response[9], command not found : rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, deployment

Every time I try to deploy my Rails app to Google App Engine I get "Error response[9], command not found: rails s".I followed Google's documentation for deploying a Rails app to Googles App Engine and everything appears to work up until "updating service", it then fails after a few minutes and gives me error response nine, saying that Rails server command was not found and I should run bundle install to install missing gems (which I tried in the App Engine console).

Here is my app.yml file

```
runtime: ruby
env: flex
entrypoint: rails server



env_variables:
SECRET_KEY_BASE:          XXXXXXXXXXX

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.lock$
- public/uploads
```

I have spent days searching Stack Overflow and the Internet, in general, trying to solve this problem but everything I have tried has produced the same error. Does anyone have any tips on how I can solve it? Or if you think you have a helpful link to someone with a similar issue that was solved that would also be cool. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I can run everything fine locally both using rails rack up and rails server, i only get the command not found when deploying to google cloud.

Here is my entire gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more:                 https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'rack'



gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'

gem 'layzr-rails'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

gem 'carrierwave','~> 1.0'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger         console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console'     anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'

  gem 'faker'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Added at 2018-06-20 10:57:17 -0700 by desktop-2stoub1\zoomd:
gem "dotenv-rails", "~> 2.4"
```

Here is my error stack trace from logs( Only thing that is shown is command not found basically)
2018-07-17 18:58:36 default[20180717t115001]  bundler: command not found: rails
2018-07-17 18:58:36 default[20180717t115001]  Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

EDIT: Found where the problem is happening

Step #1: bundler: failed to load command: rake (/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/rake)
Step #1: [91mBundler::GemNotFound: Could not find gem 'rails (~> 5.2.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:289:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:257:in`each'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:257:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:48:in`start'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:22:in `resolve'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:258:in`resolve'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:171:in `specs'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:238:in`specs_for'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:227:in `requested_specs'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in`block in definition_method'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler.rb:107:in`setup'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
Step #1:   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'[0m[91m

It looks like none of the gems are being loaded from the rubygems source for some reason. It does work locally, i only get this error on deployment. Does gcloud need the gems from a different source?

Comment: It is a good practice to remove personal sensitive information before posting a question on SO. Regarding your issue, could you post the full error trace so that we could have a better understanding of the issue? Also, did you try to run the app locally? Are there any errors when run locally? Another good thing would also be providing the contents of the Gemfile in your question post.

Comment: I completely forgot about censoring the secret key, i did not even think about it. Thanks for pointing that out, and i have updated my post with more information if that helps.

Comment: Sorry Justin, you said "I followed Google's documentation for deploying a Rails app to Googles App Engine". Could you share your link to check that documentation? Also, have you checked the  different options that can be used for the entrypoint provided here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime#application_startup